# Return a result set from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Let say I made the necessary declarations for the stored procedure and begin the stored procedure

```
BEGIN

IF (@TYPE = 0)  
    BEGIN
        SELECT @AMOUNT = ((@TOTAL_MONEY )/(12))
        SELECT @INTEREST_AMOUNT = 0           
        SELECT @TOTAL_MONEY AS TOTAL_MONEY , @AMOUNT AS AMOUNT , @INTEREST_AMOUNT AS INTEREST_AMOUNT , DATEADD(m,0,@BEGIN_DATE) AS DATE_

        @ORDER_NO=1 
        WHILE ((@ORDER_NO) <= ((@COUNT) -1 ) )  
            BEGIN   
                SELECT @INTEREST_AMOUNT =  (@TOTAL_MONEY - (@AMOUNT))* (@INTEREST_RATE/100)
                SELECT @MONEY AS MONEY_ , @AMOUNT AS PROMISE_AMOUNT , @INTEREST_AMOUNT AS INTEREST_AMOUNT , DATEADD(m,@COUNT,@BEGIN_DATE) AS DATE_
                SELECT @COUNT=@COUNT -1
            END                     
    END 
 END
```

QUESTION IS:  I want to turn a result set but this procedure turn row by row
so I made a temp table and select as below but I don't want to use a temp table but just return a result set from my stored procedure

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE
(

    TOTAL_MONEY decimal (19,3), 
    AMOUNT decimal (19,3), 
    INTEREST_AMOUNT decimal (19,3), 
    DATE_ date          

);
INSERT @TEMP  EXEC --HERE I CALL MY STORED PROCESURE with parameters IE: spinterest ..., ...., ...
SELECT * FROM @TEMP;
```

Comment: That's not a question, but it is a run-on sentence.  Please reword.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last two lines of your code to the following one line:

```
EXEC --HERE I CALL MY STORED PROCESURE with parameters IE: spinterest ..., ...., ...
```

I don't know what your parameters look like, but, you had said they were already set up.

Comment: Dear Michael you miss understand my question i think. i get a result set when i use temp table and select from it. But i do not want to use temp table but i want to directly get a result set from the procedure but with while loop and select inside i get the results but separatly i mean row by row but not in one result set. how can i get a result set from my sp without using the declare temp table part? thanks in advance.

Comment: @modestandcutegirl: simple: **don't use** a while loop (that's horribly bad RBAR - row-by-agonizing-row - processing, and should be avoided at all costs) and a temp table - just create a single `SELECT` that returns the data you're interested in....

Comment: how will i make it in my case :( i mean i used while in my procedure